# Qt Adjusting axes does not adjust the chart itself

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently trying to get my head around Line Charts in Qt. For some reason, my charts seem to show really weird behavior. When I am using the createDefaultAxis it will set the minimum and maximum values according to the minimum and maximum values of the Series behind the chart. While this seems alright at first it's already different from the behavior in [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtcharts-linechart-example.html). The minimum Y-Value there is 1, the minimum value on the axis, however, is 0.

At first, I thought this might just be due to a change to the QChart class, so I created my own Axis and tried again. This time I made the y-Axis range from 0 to 100 and the x-Axis range from 1 to 52. Also, I changed the tick counts to 4 and 52. However, the chart still looked like before and didn't seem to be affected by the changes to the axis.

I included a screenshot of that program here

[image]

I hope you can help me fix that. The goal would be that the values of the series match the values on the axes.

Edit: Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();

    series->append(0, 6);
    series->append(2, 4);
    series->append(3, 8);
    series->append(7, 4);
    series->append(10, 5);
    *series << QPointF(11, 1) << QPointF(13, 3) << QPointF(17, 6) << QPointF(18, 3) << QPointF(20, 2);

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    QValueAxis *axisX = new QValueAxis();
        axisX->setRange(1, 52);
        axisX->setMin(1);
        axisX->setMax(52);
        axisX->setTickCount(52);

        QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis();
        axisY->setRange(0, 100);
        axisY->setMin(0);
        axisY->setMax(100);
        axisY->setTickCount(4);
        chart->setAxisX(axisX);
        chart->setAxisY(axisY);
    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(400, 300);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `series` isn't attached to any axis,  it will by default scale to utilize the entire plot area of the chart.

You should attach the `series` to axis created as :

```
//... After setting up your axis X and Y
chart->setAxisX(axisX);
chart->setAxisY(axisY);

//attach the series to the specific axis.
series->attachAxis(axisX);
series->attachAxis(axisY);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add axis on the chart, use the following code:

```
addAxis(xAxis,postion); addAxis(yAxis,postion);
```

and then attach `series` to it.